# GDI+ drawing becomes corrupted when ClientSize changes

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I need to draw a circle with the size of the entire form. I have made a Form1 with the following Paint event handler:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, 0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
}
```

The problem is that when you change the size of the form or maximize it the drawing becomes corrupted. Please help me how to avoid this problem. Sorry I haven't found an appropriate topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Painting for container controls like Form was optimized, they only redraw the part of the window that was revealed by the resize.  In other words, if the user drags the right or bottom edge then there's no repaint at all when the window is made smaller.  A small repaint if it is made bigger, only the part of the window to became visible.

This is *normally* very appropriate since they don't have much reason to completely repaint themselves, they only draw their background.  This matters in particular when the user resizes the window by dragging a corner, that can generate a storm of repaint requests.  And if repainting is slow then that gets to be very visible, moving the mouse makes the motion "stutter", flicker can be noticeable as well.

But you care, you *need* to completely redraw the ellipse since you use the ClientSize property in your paint event handler.

Whether or not this optimization is turned on is determined by a style flag for the control, as Sriram pointed out.  Turning this off is so common that Winforms exposed the style flag through a simple property to make it easier to change it:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
```

Note the DoubleBuffered property, another example of a convenience property that actually changed ControlStyles.  You want this turned on to suppress the flicker your window exhibits.  Caused by first drawing the background, which erases your ellipse, then repainting the ellipse.

There's another pretty serious problem in your code, SolidBrush is a disposable class.  Disposing objects is optional, but skipping this for System.Drawing objects is quite unwise.  If you resize your window frequently enough, 10000 times, then your program will crash.  That sounds like a lot, but it is not when you set ResizeRedraw to true since that generates a lot of repaints.  Only the garbage collector can keep you out of trouble, it won't in a simple program like this.  Fix:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor)) {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, 0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

Btw, do *not* optimize this by keeping the brush around as recommended in another post.  Creating a brush is very cheap, takes about a microsecond.  But is far too expensive to keep around, it is allocated on a heap that's shared by all programs that run on the desktop.  A limited resource, that heap is small and programs start failing badly when the that heap is out of storage.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. this.DoubleBuffered = true actually removes flicker. Concerning the last part of your answer, please tell me, can I use the static property Brushes.Black as the argument to FillEllipse?

Comment: Sure, that's okay.  Being able to change the color of the brush with a property is otherwise desirable.  Your program won't work well on a machine where the user selected one of the high-contrast color schemes, common for users that have a visual impairment.  You'll paint black on top of black.  Details, details :)

Comment: @HansPassant Just asking you a question that came to my mind.Does the compiler do Runtime Memory allocation using Heap?The variables are local to the procedure call,the Active Records can be pushed and popped from a stack.So why does it go for heap allocation?

Comment: That's a big question, you ought to ask it.  Roughly, System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms have wrapper classes for operating system objects.  Like a brush or a window.  These are pure unmanaged objects and don't get allocated on the GC heap.  They are allocated in a special heap that's associated with the desktop, otherwise an OS implementation detail.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok,Just got a rough idea :)

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please tell me, if I'm creating Graphics object by the statement "Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics()", do I need to dispose it?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to enable `ResizeRedraw`. Add the following to your constructor.

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't it equivalent to the solution that jmcilhinney has suggested?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that option. Yes, it is effectively very similar to what I suggested but is probably slightly more efficient because it's done internally rather than in an event handler. Now that I'm aware of it, I'd go for that solution rather than what I suggested, although what I suggested has worked for me in the past so is not actually wrong if you want to stick with it.

Comment: I believe both are not same. but they does the same job. `ResizeRedraw` says the OS that control needs to be repainted when there is a resize, where as that solution is capturing the change in size and asking OS to repaint it immediately for you

Answer (score 0):

On Forms `Resize` event paste this ;

```
this.Refresh();
```

this will redraw the form and fire the Form1.Paint event.

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because only part of the form's area gets invalidated when the size changes.  What you need to do is handle the SizeChanged event and call the form's Refresh method.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Graphics.Clear();` before drawing to clear the old graphics  and avoid creating redundant brushes.Put the code for the Brush creation outside the block

```
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

{
        e.Graphics.Clear();
         e.Graphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, 0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice to avoid creating redundant brushes

Comment: If you want to use a SolidBrush of a standard colour then you should use the appropriate property of the Brushes class, e.g. Brushes.Black.